# impact resistant windows

Tags: windows, replacement

We have been looking for replacement windows. Our area requires hurricane impact resistant windows, We are getting a quote from Storm Tight Windows, Inc. their top of line vinyl. What is your opinion of them and what should we expect for cost 15 windows 36x60 DH

Comment: This is probably a question better suited for a place like http://www.vinyl-replacement-windows.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=1

Answer (score 2):

Whomever told you that hurricane windows are "required" wasn't being exactly truthful. The only requirement is that the window opening must be hurricane compliant which can be achieved through a combination of windows and shutters and will eliminate window breakage.

The biggest drawback of hurricane impact windows (besides price) is that they will not survive a large missile impact and will have to be replaced. I have yet to understand why they are even allowed to use the term "impact" in their name - it's the one thing that they don't do well at all. To prove this do an internet video search for "impact window test" and you will see what happens to impact windows when they are struck. They do a superb job of withstand high wind loads and keeping the hurricane winds from entering the building. They are also good at reducing noise and therefore work great at elevations of the 3 floor and up. However when it comes to using them on the 2 lower floors, it is recommended that they be shuttered to stop impact damage and the ensuing costs and inconvenience. They are fragile and are easy targets for vandals.

Some window folks like to entice you with energy savings figures but those claims are erroneous and the payback has been estimated by independent, non-window replacement industry laboratories of at least 40 years. A little internet research goes a long way in helping you see through most of these falsehoods.

You may want to opt for a good quality energy saving non-impact window and cover them with a fabric or mesh type of impact system. If you want better protection there are roll-down shutters or accordion types, too. If you want the top of the line there are the flat, crystal clear, flat polycarbonate style.

Two simple rules to remember:
1. If it's made from glass it's going to break.
2. Aluminum frames are stronger and last longer that plastic frames.

Whatever you choose do your research, ask questions and get the answers in writing. Some salespeople will tell you anything to close the deal. Good luck!